# Error while Trying to keep a list of message properties file in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I tried to create Message source based on the tutorials in java brains, I ran into a problem while trying to put the option to have more than one message properties file an error was produced, the error is given below

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'basename'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'basename': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:413)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at test.app.main(app.java:20)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'basename'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'basename': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:481)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:518)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:512)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1371)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1330)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'basename': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:233)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:466)
```

The spring.xml file is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd"     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename">
        <list>
            <value>mymessages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="test"/>
```

When i removed the list tag from the above code the i was able to run without exception. the void main is given below.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    System.out.println(context.getMessage("greeting", null, "hiiiii", null));
}
```

I have created a file mymessages.prperties with on key value pair that is greeting. Please help me find what i did wrong in this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using `<property name="basename">` that should be for single resource..
But for multiple resources you shoud use `<property name="basenames">`..
your error message clearly states that, can't covert from string to List.. you are using string type but passing list type.. so use `basenames`..
Hope it helps...

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
<property name="basename">
```

to:

```
<property name="basenames">
                        ^
```